# Expand Dropdownmenu onkeyup event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

When I click on the input my dropdownmenu is expanded, what I need is to expand it automatically Onkeyup event.

I'm trying the following but not working.

HTML

```
<div class="btn-group DropDownMenu">
    <input id="input1" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle btn-select" data-toggle="dropdown" type="text" onkeyup = "Filter()">
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
function Filter() {
    //some other code 
    $("#input1").click();
}
```

Any thoughts ? I'm using bootstrap btw

Comment: Did you declare `function Filter()` as it was edited?

Comment: Your jquery selector syntax is wrong. Put a hashtag in front of input1 - $("#input1").click();

Comment: remove `data-toggle="dropdown"` from your `input` and than add `$('.btn-group > input').on('keyup', function() { $(this).closest('.btn-group).addClas('open'); /* EVENT */ });`

Comment: I updated the post; I was  just in a hurry and forget the # and function key. @RobertE.McIntosh I'll try this

Answer (score 0):

remove `class="dropdown-toggle"` and `data-toogle="dropdown"` from input and this to JS

```
$(".dropdown").keyup(function (event) {
   //preventing default behaviour of bootstrap
    event.stopPropagation();
    $('.dropdown-menu').dropdown().toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where have you written the javascript.
I have created a fiddle and changed the javascript a little:

```
window.Filter = function() {
    $("#input1").click();
}
```

it is working in the fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/dyo8fowt/